# Count from a Count based on a condition in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables in my database.

1. `Students` (`Idno, Name, CourseId`)

Sample data:

```
Idno    Name    CourseId
------------------------
-101123456  Vijay   101
-101123457  John    102
-101123458  Sam 101
-101123459  Arvind  102
-101123460  Smith   101
```

2. `Courses` (`CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName, StreamId`)

Sample data:

```
CourseId    CourseNo     CourseName StreamId
------------------------------------------
-101    53245   C   1
-102    53245   C++ 2
```

3. `Streams` (`StreamId, StreamName`)

Sample data:

```
StreamId    StreamName  
---------------------------
-1          Engineering
-2          Medical
```

4. `Booking` (`BId, Idno, BStatus`)

Sample data:

```
Bid     Idno        BStatus
--------------------------------
-1110   101123456   Confirmed
-1111   101123456   Confirmed
-1112   101123457   Confirmed
-1113   101123458   Confirmed
-1114   101123459   Confirmed
-1115   101123460   Confirmed
-1116   101123456   Confirmed
-1117   101123457   Confirmed
-1118   101123458   Confirmed
-1119   101123459   Confirmed
-1119   101123460   Cancelled
```

I have a problem generating the following output

```
SNo Stream        BookedOnce BookedTwice NonBooked
1    Engineering     2           3         0
2    Medical         3           1          1
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this requires a two step process.  First, calculate the number of bookings by each student for a stream.  Then per stream, count the number of students that have one, two or zero bookings.

Here's an example, with the first step in the inner query:

```
select  StreamId
,       StreamName
,       sum(case when Bookings = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BookedOnce
,       sum(case when Bookings = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as BookedTwice
,       sum(case when Bookings = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NoneBooked
from    (
        select  str.StreamId
        ,       str.StreamName
        ,       s.Idno
        ,       count(b.BId) as Bookings
        from    Students s
        left join
                Booking b
        on      b.Idno = s.Idno
        left join
                Courses c
        on      c.CourseId = s.CourseId
        left join
                Streams str
        on      str.StreamId = c.StreamId
        group by        
                str.StreamId
        ,       str.StreamName
        ,       s.Idno
        ) BookingsPerStudentPerStream
group by        
        StreamId
,       StreamName
```

Comment: Thanks alot Its working very fine. But I have small Issue,Instead of null, can I get "0". And in NonBooked Column I would like to get the no. of students who have not booked yet(i.e., Total no.of students-(BookedOnce+BookedTwice))

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Good point about `str`, but your other comment is not very helpful

Comment: Adding `else 0` should avoid the `null` results. Total number of students probably works better if you move `Students` to the left part of the `left join`, I've edited that into the answer.

Comment: No, I'm still getting "0" in "NonBooked" column. If there are 500 engineering students and 10 students bookedonce, 30 students booked twice then in "NonBooked" Column I should get 460 (i.e.,500-(10+30))

Comment: Hmm, `count(*)` counts even students without a booking as having one booking. Try `count(b.bID)` instead?  If the output is still unexpected, post an example of a student that is counted in the wrong way.

Comment: Im getting the initial desired output, but now I have some small change in output. I need to know how many students have not booked yet for atleast single time? in the last column.